# new object with brackets as property name

Tags: c#, object, json.net

How could I produce this JSON:

```
{"{}":""}
```

From this code:

```cs
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    brackets = ""
})
```

`brackets` should be replaced by `{}`

Comment: I guess, you can achieve this using a string-to-string dictionary with 1 pair inside. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string> { ["{}"] = "" })`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thank you. Wouldn't there be a "cleaner" way tho?

Comment: This is an odd question, so how about `var json = "{\"{}\":\"\"}";`?

Comment: Try to create a class with one property named `Brackets` and mark it with an attribute `[JsonProperty(Name = "{}")]`, let's see if it works :)

Comment: Or you can use JObject -  `new JObject {   { "{}", "" } };`

Comment: @Fabjan This look like a clean way, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"{}" is a string, just like any other string, so you can use it as a key like you usually do.

There are two ways to achieve this.

Use a dictionary of string-to-string with custom name:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{
    ["{}"] = ""
};
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Use a class with custom property name:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "{}")]
    public string Brackets { get; set; }
}

// Usage:
var obj = new MyClass { Brackets = "" };
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that sets the property name using [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm):

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("{}")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo { Value = "" } );
```